# How to generate header image alt text in a custom WordPress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, accessibility, alt

I am building a custom WordPress theme without plugins. The header image for each page may be different, so I am using the dashboard to assign the image and calling the "get_header_image()" function in my theme's code. The header image is properly displayed, but the alt text is not.

I wrote the following code:

```
function alt_text_display() {
    $header_id = get_header_image(get_the_ID());
    $alt = get_post_meta($header_id, 'wp_get_attachment_image_alt', true);
    echo $alt;
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'alt_text_display' );
```

It doesn't work, probably because get_header_iamge() doesn't take arguments, right?

My HTML looks like this:

```
    <div class="hero_container">
          <img src="<?php echo( get_header_image() ); ?>" class="hero">
     </div>
```

I set the image's alt text when I uploaded it to the media library. That text is not showing. Instead, the site's title is showing. How do I display the alt text that I set in the Media Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's my custom function

```
function alt_text_display() {

        $data =  get_object_vars(get_theme_mod('header_image_data'));
        $image_id = is_array($data) && isset($data['attachment_id']) 
                    ? $data['attachment_id'] : false;

        if ($image_id) {

            $image_alt = get_post_meta( $image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
            return image_alt;

        }

    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'alt_text_display' );
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="hero_container">
                    <img src="<?php echo( get_header_image() ); ?>" alt="<?php echo( alt_text_display() ); ?>"  class="hero">
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot to add "alt" attribute in html and call function inside it.

```
<div class="hero_container">
      <img src="<?php echo( get_header_image() ); ?>" alt="<?php display_alt_text(); ?>" class="hero">
 </div>
```

Or you can use wp_get_attachment_image inside html to output image:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID(), array('700', '600'), "", array( "alt" => "My image alt text here" ) );  ?>
```

Comment: Hello Arturas. thank you for replying. Putting an alt tag in the theme code will overwrite the alt text I applied to the image when I uploaded it to the Media Library. I see I could have been clearer with my ask.